# Git, find remote branch where file contains text

Tags: java, git, grep

I want to find name of the remote branch, where java class *Foo* has a method *byte[] getByteArray()*.

As there are many remote branches, I don't want to check them out first locally and grep each (until there is a command to pull all remote branches).

Does git provide some function to scan all the remote branches (not necessarily pulled locally) and find the branch (or latest commit in any branch) where a specific method was added, where it's present in a class or where it was removed? Either by java-type aware manner or string matching.

Comment: "I don't want to check them out and grep" - why not?  This is like 4 lines of Bash or something.

Comment: You don't have to checkout to files, but you need to fetch them

Answer (score 0):

commands like the following should show where it exists currently

```
git fetch origin
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin|while read sha type ref; do if git grep -q getByteArray "$sha" -- src/com/mycompany/myproject/Foo.java ; then echo "found in $ref"; fi; done
```

substitute your path and remote name instead